# Detect if folder contains Log folder and ps1 file

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a menu for our support teams scripts, which is mostly working. However, when it finds a folder that has both a folder called "Logs" and a script (.ps1) I want it to launch the script instead of listing them as a menu. I have created 2 if statements to try and detect it, but I cannot figure out why they are not working.

`$Directories` is filling up correctly and the `Write-Host` of item 0 and 1 in it are printing the correct items (log folder and a script). However, the `if` statements are always going false so it's skipping the `if`s. Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
$Directories = Get-ChildItem

Write-Host $Directories[0]
Write-Host $Directories[1]
if ($Directories[0] -eq 'Logs' -or $Directories[0] -like '*.ps1') {
    Write-Host "first if"
    if ($Directories[1] -eq 'Logs' -or $Directories[1] -like '*.ps1') {
        Write-Host "Second If"
    }
} else {
    foreach ($Item in $Directories) {
        $ItemName = $Item -replace "-"," "
        if ($Item -like '*.ps1') {
            $ItemName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($ItemName)
            Write-Host $MenuNum": "$ItemName -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host $MenuNum": "$ItemName -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        $MenuNum ++
    }
```

Expected result is when there is no log folder and no .ps1 file, it will carry on further down the script and create a menu. If there is a log folder and a .ps1 file it will instead launch the .ps1. Currently I'm just testing so I have the `Write-Host` for now.

Comment: you describe the decision as `not this AND not that` but your test is `this OR that` ... what do you actually want to test?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a bit unclear what you are trying to do exactly, I think you want to recurse a certain root folder and list all directories in there.
If a directory is found that has (at least) one .ps1 script file in it, then get that script file and launch it (or for now, write it out in in Green). Otherwise, just write out the found directory in Yellow.

Try this:

```
$MenuNum = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\test' -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $MenuNum++
    $scriptFile = if ($_.Name -eq 'Logs') {
        # we've found a directory called 'Logs'
        # test if it has at least one .ps1 file in it
        # emit the first (or only) found ps1 FileInfo object. $null if nothing there.
        @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter '*.ps1' -File)[0]
    }
    if ($scriptFile) {
        # launch the (first or only) script file or whatever you want to do with it
        Write-Host ('{0}: {1}' -f $MenuNum, $scriptFile.FullName) -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        # just write the directory name
        Write-Host ('{0}: {1}' -f $MenuNum, $_.FullName) -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
}
```

The output will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) returns a list of objects not a list of strings, so you need to use the property name to check for equality.

```
$Directories[0].Name -eq 'Logs'
```

If you only want to work with file names, you can use the following:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like to collect all the *.ps1 files from folders named LOGS and execute them?

If I understand it correctly, I would like to start first with the statement, that **I WOULD NOT ENCOURAGE RUNNING SCRIPTS FROM FOLDERS, WITHOUT ANY CONTROL OR SECURITY!**

Still to provide you with an answer, you may try the following:

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path *LOGS* -Include *.ps1 -Recurse
foreach ($file in $FileList) {
    & ($File.fullname)
}
```

This would collect all the files into a variable, then you may loop them for execution, 
**BUT USE THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK!**

Hope it helps!

Best regards, 
Ivan